# UTF-8 Characters Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: php, html, unicode, utf-8, meta

I am trying to echo some utf-8 characters with PHP. But They Didn't Display Correctly.

Here Is The Code With Php.`<?php echo "➨៚ ⃟⃢⌽⍲ͥនͣн⃟ᨖᴋ⃟ɨиɢⷨ⌽ ⃟⃢☬࿐ is your symbolic id"; ?>`

Also, I Have `<meta charset="utf-8">` In My head Tag.

But Its Displaying Like This
[image].

How Can I Fix This?

Comment: i think it means that the browser physically cannot support the UTF chars. Plus, if your browser cannot support them, it usually means your users won't be able to see them either, and it is recommended then to not use them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set your PHP script's charset to UTF-8 as well:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks. I Have Done This. It Worked For Desktop Browser. But Mobile Browsers Still Like Old One. Can I Do Something For That

Comment: Which mobile browser are you using?

Comment: chrome & samsung internet

Answer (score 0):

White squares are *missing character glyph*s in your font:

- text "➨៚ ⃟⃢⌽⍲ͥនͣн⃟ᨖᴋ⃟ɨиɢⷨ⌽ ⃟⃢☬࿐ is your symbolic id"
- code `"➨៚ ⃟⃢⌽⍲ͥនͣн⃟ᨖᴋ⃟ɨиɢⷨ⌽ ⃟⃢☬࿐ is your symbolic id"`

See

- [Character Code/Glyph Mapping Requirements and Recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM07/appendixB.html) or
- [cmap — Character to Glyph Index Mapping Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap#overview).

Compare *text* and *code* items in above bulleted list with the following partial screenshot of answer editing window and its preview:

[image: missing character glyphs]